# Cucumber Junit Runner not showing line of testcase

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I recently upgraded the cucumber dependencies from 4.8.0 to the newest version:

```
[group: "io.cucumber", name: "cucumber-java", version: "6.6.0"],
[group: "io.cucumber", name: "cucumber-junit", version: "6.6.0"],
```

When running tests from IntelliJ, it only shows me the number of the test case, but not the line in which it is written in. This makes it really hard to use, if one file contains multiple scenarios or has even more test cases than this one. It gets even worse, if the file contains comments or disabled tests.

This is how it looks for me:

[image]

Double clicking does not point to the failed test case and does not even open the feature file.

If I am not mistaken it was showing the line before, but does not anymore. It sometimes (not always) reference the file and at which step it failed, but again, it does not show me, which case failed, only at which step definition.

Comment: You might need to update the Cucumber plugin for your IDE. (And the plugins are not always up to date with the latest Cucumber version, so you might have to wait for the plugin to catch up, or downgrade Cucumber to a version supported by the plugin)

Comment: @Marit I am only using the Gherkin plugin for writing feature files. I haven't used any other cucumber plugins.

Comment: Then you might need to update that one.

Comment: If your IDEA version is up to date you can left-click on a node in the test tree and select Jump to Source (or press F4).

Comment: If you select a node for a step, it will jump to the step. If you select the node with an example it will jump to the line of that example.

Comment: Thanks, pressing F4 on the node I want to access works! :) If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'stepNotifications = true' to the @CucumberOptions which shows all cucumber steps while executing.

Comment: I tried that before posting here. It didn't solve my problem, because it does not display the line number, only all the extra steps, which weren't that useful tbh. Pressing F4 on the failing test brings me directly to the line of the failing test case.